# QTreeView custom row height of individual rows

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

Is it possible to redefine the row height of certain individual rows within a `QTreeView`?

I have a custom `QTreeView`, custom `QAbstractItemModel` and a custom `QStyledItemDelegate`, but it seems that all the `sizeHint` methods are either called only once (initially) or are not virtual in the base classes.

Qt Version 4.7.4, no upgrade to 5 possible.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is SizeHintRole, try to return QSize(int,int) inside your data() method When this role requested.

Comment: Same behavior: The data() method is only called once with the SizeHintRole set!

Comment: So if you need call data again to update something, then normal practice is to emit dataChanged signal with needed QModelIndex'es from model, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't explicit enough. The `QAbstractItemModel::data()` method with the `SizeHintRole` set is only called once for the complete tree and not - as expected - for each item. And yes, I do emit the `dataChanged` signal as soon as data within the model changes. Currently, the model only changes once during initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reimplement the delegate’s sizeHint(). Found an example in some production code of mine. It is shown simplified below. In the example, the tree may contain images. Therefore the cell sizes need to be adjusted to host the images.

```
class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
  public:
      QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
      {
           const TreeItem* ti(static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer()));
           if(ti->pixmap())
              return ti->pixmap()->size();
           QItemDelegate::sizeHint(option,index);
      }
};
```

Usage:

```
 QTreeView view;
 ItemDelegate *delegate = new ItemDelegate;
 view.setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

Comment: I've already reimplemented the `sizeHint` method. The problem is that this method is called only once for the complete tree (i.e. only for the root `QModelIndex`) such that all rows have the same size.

Comment: @mefiX probably, you forgor about http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#uniformRowHeights-prop

Comment: @SaZ: You are correct. In fact that is probably the answer.

Comment: @SaZ: You were right, I must have set the `uniformRowHeight` property to true by accident. Turning it off solved my problem.